# assigning sql parameter to a textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = sqlconn.CreateCommand
    sqlconn.Open()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "DeletetblOfficeEquipmentProfileRecord"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OEID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11, "oeq-su-999")
    cmd.Parameters("@OEID").Value = "oeq-su-999"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlconn.Close()
```

above is my stored procedure how can I assign txtOEID.text a textbox
to serve as the value for @OEID parameter?

my stored procedure is delete columns WHERE OEID value in textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I assign txtOEID.text a textbox to serve as the value for
>   @OEID

Currently you are assigning it a string, replace it with your `txtOEID.Text` property like:

```
cmd.Parameters("@OEID").Value = txtOEID.Text
```

Comment: sir i need 3 minutes more to accept answer i dont know why. dont worry i will

Comment: @ivandinglasan, thats ok, take your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
variable_name=textbox1.text
command.Params.Add("@OEID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11, variable_name)
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue  this line gives me an blue underlign in the code sir